# How to remove index from a created Dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have created a Dataframe `df` by merging 2 lists using the following command:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name' : list1,'Probability' : list2})
```

But I'd like to remove the first column (The index column) and make the column called `Name` the first column. I tried using `del df['index']` and `index_col=0`. But they didn't work. I also checked `reset_index()` and that is not what I need. I would like to completely remove the whole index column from a Dataframe that has been created like this (As mentioned above). Someone please help!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-reset-index):

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [2,5]
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name' : list1,'Probability' : list2})
print (df)
   Name  Probability
0     1            2
1     2            5

df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
print (df)
      Probability
Name             
1               2
2               5
```

If you need also remove index `name`:

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
#pandas 0.18.0 and higher
df = df.rename_axis(None)
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
#df.index.name = None
print (df)
   Probability
1            2
2            5
```

Comment: There is an insane algorithm that I'm working on. I have used up all my brain cells on it in the last 2 days haha. I'll ask for help if I can't figure it out by tonight.

Comment: I can try it or maybe someone else. I hope you found solution. Good luck!

Comment: @jezrael This serves the purpose but the id is misplaced in the row. Any fix for that ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to save your dataframe to a spreadsheet for a report.. it is possible to format the dataframe to eliminate the index column using xlsxwriter.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Probability" + ".xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Probability', startrow=3, startcol=0, index=False)

writer.save()
```

index=False will then save your dataframe without the index column.

I use this all the time when building reports from my dataframes.

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way is to hide the index using the hide_index method

```
df = df.style.hide_index()
```

this will hide the index from the dataframe.

Comment: Did you check this Somesh? On my system this method returns a `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler` object, not a `DataFrame`

Comment: @user1330734 it works, I have tested it with my dataset. can you post your error here? it seems from you error the object you are trying to convert is not a dataframe.

Comment: ```>>> type(df)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> df2 = df.style.hide_index()
>>> type(df2)
<class 'pandas.io.formats.style.Styler'>
```

Comment: This solution has to install `Jinja2`. That raise this error: `Missing optional dependency 'Jinja2'. DataFrame.style requires jinja2. Use pip or conda to install Jinja2. `